# ShowHide bookmark on text value not working

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform

I need to hide a row in a table if there is no value in a textbox on my user form.  The document template has bookmarks throughout and I've been using code below on Change to show/hide bookmarked text based on checkboxes, option buttons and combo lists - all those work great.  My last step is to apply this same concept to rows based on whether or not there is a textbox value.  How can I manipulate this code so it works on rows in a table?  The row I want to hide is bookmarked.

```
Set pRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("T6_Keep2").Range
If T6_Founder1.Value = True Then
    With pRng.Font
      .Hidden = True
    End With
    With ActiveWindow.View
      .ShowHiddenText = False
      .ShowAll = False
    End With
Else
    With pRng.Font
      .Hidden = False
    End With
    With ActiveWindow.View
      .ShowHiddenText = True
      .ShowAll = True
    End With
End If
Set pRng = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word doesn't have the functionality to "hide" a table row. Best you can do is to format the text as hidden, set the HeightRule to "exactly" and the row heigt to 0. You may still see a bit of the row in the layout on-screen, but it appears not to print if you look at the page in print preview - at least on my machine. You might also want to do something with the borders, depending on exactly how it does appear. Example code:

```
Dim rngBkm as Word.Range
Dim rw as Word.Row
Set rngBkm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("test").Range
Set rw = rngBkm.Rows(1)
rw.Range.Font.Hidden = true
rw.HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
rw.rng.Height = 0
```